# How to get SelectedItem from Primefaces SelectOneMenu?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have wrote a `Validator` in JSf2 to validate two input fields but for this validation i want to know the  `selecteditem` from the `SelectOneMenu`

I tried below code but its not working

```
    SelectOneMenu selectOneMenu = (SelectOneMenu) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("tabView:dialogWindow:valueType");
    selectOneMenu.get
    UIInput  submittedVal = (UIInput)selectOneMenu.getSubmittedValue();
```

But this is giving  `Null` .

Can i have to go through the child of `selectOneMenu` or something else?

Comment: @BalusC  I want to know how to access selecteditem from the SelectOneMenu .I know how to get component in Validator that i already done .

Comment: I know. The duplicate answers how to get value of another component in a custom validator. Try reading answer from top to bottom.

Comment: Ok Got you point `selectOneMenu.getValue();` because its already validated so this  `selectOneMenu.getSubmittedValue();` is coming `NULL`